# NPM cant find module, win 7/64 bit

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd

I just have installed node for windows 64 bit with the msi installer from node.js site, on windows 7 64 bit. It sad that it install node path and npm(node package manager). And when I type node in CMD it goes to interactive console and I can run .js scripts with it(it's working). But when I type npm I get this error. I did not change any paths and it's a fresh install.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Comment: Windows command line or cygwin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well APPARENTLY, problem is in 64 bit version of windows installer, the 32 bit is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest downloading git bash for windows. That should solve most cmd problems.

Answer (score 0):

You may change the PATH variable to `C:\Program Files\nodejs'` instead of `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin`.